# Check if a program is running by executable path

Tags: powershell, process, system

In powershell, how do I check if a program is running by using the full path of the program executable? Or do I need to parse the path to get the process name?

Thanks.

EDIT:

I need to know if the executable "C:\My Temporary Programs\Test 1.exe" is running.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
get-process | ?{$_.path -eq $path}
```

So you can do something like:

```
if(get-process | ?{$_.path -eq "C:\My Temporary Programs\Test 1.exe"}){
    #exe is running. Do what you want
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$exePath = 'C:\My Temporary Programs\Test 1.exe'

$isRunning = (get-wmiobject win32_process | ? { 
    $_.Path -eq $exePath
 } | measure-object | % { $_.Count }) -gt 0



# $isRunning is now a boolean value, set to true if there is one or
# more instances running
```